# My fopen function works, but the fwrite function doesn't

Tags: php, file, fopen, fwrite

So I'm trying to create a file and write code into that file whenever a user submits a register and successfully moves on to the activation stage.  I'm doing this so that I can store all of the variables and information in my registration php file into the file I create.  This is relevant code of the signup form:

```
#$file is set in removed code
$filename = '../' . $file;
fopen($filename, "w") or die("<h1 style='text-align: center; color: red;'>There has been an error creating your user files. Try again later.</h1>");
$content = "
<?php

potato

?>
";
fwrite($filename,  $content);
```

Everything works, except for the `fwrite()` function.  I looked at the file I created, and nothing appears in it.  What's going on?

Comment: Perhaps you could come up with a more minimal example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: The `fopen()` function returns a file handle (on success), and you use that file handle as an argument in `fwrite()`, not a filename string

Comment: So `O'Connor` or `O'Brien` would be invalid surnames by your rules, you're restricting your userbase to avoid a lot of Irish people?

Comment: @MarkBaker No, I just didn't want special characters in the first, last, or u sername.  I should've remove the apostrophe though, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Removed all  (or at least most) of the extraneous code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) returns a stream resource bound to `$filename`. When you call [fwrite()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php), the first parameter it takes is the **resource** returned by `fopen()`. **Not** the filename.

So change the relevant part of your program to this:

```
$handle = fopen($filename, "w") or die("...");
$content = "foobar";
fwrite($handle,  $content);
fclose($handle); // Don't forget to close when you're done.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this great answer, it solved my problem!  Just one more question.  How do I store the variables in my signup form into that file I created?

Comment: You want to store variables from the signup form into a file? Why? What are you doing with the file? What format do you want the file to be in? Without knowing exactly what your goal is, perhaps you could use a format like CSV - you would write a new line to the same file for each record. To do something like this, you'd have to open the file for appending (`fopen($filename, "a")`). Then, make $content contain a csv line: `$content = "$first, $last, ...\n";`

Comment: well since I hash my cookie, retrieving the user information is quite difficult using SQL queries, so I just want to store the information in a  database and a file.  Also, I figured out how to store the user's info, thanks for the advice!